# Cloud Function HTTP Request parameter being split up at "&"

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, alamofire, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a Firebase Cloud Function call that passes a parameter that is the string representation of a particular url. For the most part, I have my Cloud Function getting the parameters with `var somePath = req.query.somePath;` and doing all the logic I would like with those variables. However, the url contains `?` and `&` symbols which I think may be confusing Alamofire into thinking that the data following the `&` is its own parameter being passed.

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
let somePath = "https://www.somewebsite.com/someSubpath?firstID=firstValue&someID=someValue"
let url = "https://us-central1-[myProjectName].cloudfunctions.net/myfunction?somePath=" + somePath + "&someData=" + someData

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
  response in
  print("original URL request")
  print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
  print("URL response")
  print(response.response as Any) // URL response
  print(response.response?.statusCode ?? "response.response?.statusCode is nil")
}
```

I am guessing that the `&` in `somePath` is causing `someID` to be treated as another parameter and so my
cloud function thinks `somePath` =

```
https://www.somewebsite.com/someSubpath?firstID=firstValue
```

but it should be =

```
https://www.somewebsite.com/someSubpath?firstID=firstValue&someID=someValue
```

With this guess in mind, I then tried
Changing:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
```

To:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["somePath": somePath ?? ""], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
```

But this just led to another error that `somePath` had not been passed as a parameter.

**Does anyone know how I can prevent `somePath` from being split up despite having `?` and `&` in it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data via query parameters, you should use query encoding instead of json like

```
let somePath = "https://www.somewebsite.com/someSubpath?firstID=firstValue&someID=someValue"
    let parameters = ["somePath":somePath,"someData":"someData"]
    let url = "https://us-central1-myProjectName.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction"


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
        Helper.shared.log(for: response)
        print("original URL request")
        print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
        print("URL response")
        print(response.response as Any) // URL response
        print(response.response?.statusCode ?? "response.response?.statusCode is nil")
    }
```

Alamofire will handle all the required escape characters.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  This makes so much sense.  Thank you so much.